# Infix expression to Binary Tree in C

Tags: c, tree, expression

I have to parse an infix expression into a binary tree.

The expression is:

```
 (((x1 + 5.12) ∗ (x2 − 7.68))/x3)
```

I don't really have a clue on how to interpret the expression. Does someone has a clue on how to process this?

Comment: @OmidCompSCI, he probably means building an AST out of an expression.

Comment: @bipll ah that'll make a bit more sense.

Answer (score 12):

Your task is not so hard, firstly you should acquaint yourself with [notation types](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/expression_parsing.htm) and then with expression parsing.

In general, to parse and evaluate an (infix) expression, you need to:

- read and tokenize it, i.e. classify each symbol as: operand, operation, etc.
- convert from infix to binary expression tree: this is usually done with algorithms such as [Shunting yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).
- create a grammar that defines operation precedence and allows strict<sup>1</sup> order of expression evaluation.

Expressions written in infix notation are slightly more difficult to parse, that is why usually they are converted to more *"machine friendly"* versions, like (reverse) [Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) which provides some advantages among which is the elimination of the need of parenthesses.

So, as you can see this is roughly the big picture and your task is a part of it. Here is a visualisation of binary expression tree for: `2 * 3 / ( 2 – 1 ) + 5 * ( 4 – 1 )`

[image]

Here is more on the topic and an example [implementation in C++](http://cplusplus.kurttest.com/notes/stack.html#binary-expression-tree).

---

<sup>1. In your case obeying the rules of Algebra.</sup>